# Duplicate a dnn site in a subdomain

Tags: dotnetnuke

Duplicate a dnn site in a subdomain from plesk
I created subdomain, transferred all files and db
At login I have DNN error. I edited records in the PortalAlias table and edited the connection string in web.config
What am I missing to work?

Having the same db and same files, I expected to go online correctly

Answer (score 1):

Some more details would be helpful. Start wit DNN version.  Then, the exact steps you followed.

If you were trying simply to change my site.com to my sub.mysite.com, just add that as a portal Alia’s.  There probably are some other minor things too.